# ipython notebook pylab fig size running twice?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I am using iPython notebook wo do some visualization.  Figures are inline (the profile defaults to interactive, as this supports a number of users who prefer interactive more frequently):

```
%pylab inline
```

Using the inline plot, I often set the fig size manually:

```
figsize(10,5)
```

I find that I need to run cells twice to realize a change in the fig size.  For example, if I define cell [1] as `figsize(10,5)` and run it, the output is the correct size.  If I then run cell [2] with `fig size(5,10)1 I get output that is of size (10,5).  A second run of cell [2] draws correctly.

Any insight into why this is occurring?  Is it due to the inline backend and I just need to live with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Something funny is going on with the state machine....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Definition: figsize(sizex, sizey)
Docstring:
Set the default figure size to be [sizex, sizey].

This is just an easy to remember, convenience wrapper that sets::

  matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [sizex, sizey]
```

This seem correct to me, if you run the following, whatever value of X, Y I always get the right plot

```
figsize(10,5)
plot(range(10))
```

if you run it after your plot, then you set the default for next plot... but without exact example, hard to say..

Comment: moving to before the plot command worked.  Makes sense that the plot size needs to be set before the plot is made.  Thanks.

Comment: Hahaha! The same here! LOL :D